# Large interval upper bound of a CGAL lazy number

Tags: c++, cgal

I have an example of a sum of the form `s = a_1/b_1 + a_2/b_2 + ...` where the `a_i` and the `b_i` are CGAL lazy numbers, such that the interval returned by `s.interval()` is very large. Its lower bound is close to the expected value (and close to `CGAL::as_double(s)`) but its upper bound is huge (even infinite).

But if I use `mydivision(a_i, b_i)` (defined below) instead of `a_i/b_i`, then the interval is thin as expected. Here is `mydivision`:

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Quotient<CGAL::MP_Float> Quotient;
typedef CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<Quotient>  lazyScalar;

lazyScalar mydivision(lazyScalar x1, lazyScalar x2) {
  Quotient q1 = x1.exact();
  Quotient q2 = x2.exact();
  lazyScalar q = lazyScalar(Quotient(
    q1.numerator() * q2.denominator(), q1.denominator() * q2.numerator())
  );
  return q;
}
```

This is the sum (it goes to `pi/2 - 1`):

[image]

This is the full code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <CGAL/number_utils.h>
#include <CGAL/Lazy_exact_nt.h>
#include <CGAL/MP_Float.h>
#include <CGAL/Quotient.h>
#include <CGAL/Interval_nt.h>

typedef CGAL::Quotient<CGAL::MP_Float> Quotient;
typedef CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<Quotient>  lazyScalar;
typedef std::vector<lazyScalar>        lazyVector;

// "my" division
lazyScalar mydivision(lazyScalar x1, lazyScalar x2) {
  Quotient q1 = x1.exact();
  Quotient q2 = x2.exact();
  lazyScalar q = lazyScalar(Quotient(
    q1.numerator() * q2.denominator(), q1.denominator() * q2.numerator())
  );
  return q;
}

// sum the elements of a vector of lazy numbers
lazyScalar lazySum(lazyVector lv) {
  const size_t n = lv.size();
  lazyScalar sum(0);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += lv[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

// element-wise division of two vectors of lazy numbers
lazyVector lv1_dividedby_lv2(lazyVector lv1, lazyVector lv2) {
  const size_t n = lv1.size();
  lazyVector lv(n);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lv[i] = lv1[i] / lv2[i];
  }
  return lv;
}

// same as above using "my" division
lazyVector lv1_mydividedby_lv2(lazyVector lv1, lazyVector lv2) {
  const size_t n = lv1.size();
  lazyVector lv(n);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lv[i] = mydivision(lv1[i], lv2[i]);
  }
  return lv;
}

// cumulative products of the elements of a vector of lazy numbers
lazyVector lazyCumprod(lazyVector lvin) {
  const size_t n = lvin.size();
  lazyVector lv(n);
  lazyScalar prod(1);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    prod *= lvin[i];
    lv[i] = prod;
  }
  return lv;
}

// the series with the ordinary division
lazyScalar Euler(int n) {
  lazyVector lv1(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lv1[i] = lazyScalar(i + 1);
  }
  lazyVector lv2(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lv2[i] = lazyScalar(2*i + 3);
  }
  return lazySum(lv1_dividedby_lv2(lazyCumprod(lv1), lazyCumprod(lv2))); 
}

// the series with "my" division
lazyScalar myEuler(int n) {
  lazyVector lv1(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lv1[i] = lazyScalar(i + 1);
  }
  lazyVector lv2(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lv2[i] = lazyScalar(2*i + 3);
  }
  return lazySum(lv1_mydividedby_lv2(lazyCumprod(lv1), lazyCumprod(lv2))); 
}

// test - the difference starts to occur for n=170
int main() {
  lazyScalar euler = Euler(171);
  CGAL::Interval_nt<false> interval = euler.approx();
  std::cout << "lower bound: " << interval.inf() << "\n"; // prints 0.57
  std::cout << "upper bound: " << interval.sup() << "\n"; // prints inf
  lazyScalar myeuler = myEuler(171);
  CGAL::Interval_nt<false> myinterval = myeuler.approx();
  std::cout << "lower bound: " << myinterval.inf() << "\n"; // prints 0.57
  std::cout << "upper bound: " << myinterval.sup() << "\n"; // prints 0.57
  return 0;
}
```

Why this large upper bound?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are computing factorials and similar products. Once they exceed the maximum value for a `double`, there isn't much an interval represented as a pair of double can do.

At least it gives you a safe answer, and you can still get the true answer using `exact()` at the end. Your division would be simpler as `return exact(x1/x2);`, but you don't even need to call `exact` that often, just `exact(Euler(171))`

Computing the value as `(1/3)*(2/5)*(3/7)` instead of `(1*2*3)/(3*5*7)` would avoid having an overflow so soon.

Comment: You're right, there's an overflow, and the interval is thin if I compute as you say. [Here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/discussions/7035#discussioncomment-4136578) is a complement.